# React application - Using tailwind and bootstrap together

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css, reactstrap

I am planning to use `tailwind` and `bootstrap` css in the same project.
I am not getting the correct styling for `tailwind css`.

Is there any alternative i can go for or should i remove `bootstrap` completely?

Comment: What specific bootstrap features are you using?

Comment: Btn classes, card component, table and layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `tailwind` and `bootstrap` just makes things more complex with no benefit. You should choose one and only one.
Both frameworks may contradict each other.

Comment: I totally agree, this will make the project more complexe and it will also confuse the future developers. It's a waste for the project. Just choose one of them and go with it, they are just a tool to help you design your UI more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you stick with `tailwind` because you have the power to control everything, now about `bootstrap`
If you need for classes such as btn ,card etc ,here is the good news, there is an amazing alternative [daisyui](https://daisyui.com) which is tailwind css component library